# How is email able to reach this person despite no MX record?

Tags: email, dns

I have an email address for someone, where the hostname to the right of the @ sign is "mail.gongin.com.tw".  When I try to do an MX record lookup on mxtoolbox.com, it reports "No Records Exist". Windows nslookup gives some information back but I don't see any "mail exchanger" data in the nslookup results.  I've also tried an MX record lookup via this [mail component](https://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) and it too finds no MX records.

I sent two test emails to this person, each from a different email service.  Both emails reached him and he replied to me.

How are these emails able to reach him?  I imagine there must be some extra lookups that the sending mail servers are doing to find a mail server to deliver the email to, and if so, would like to know how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a domain has no MX records, delivery must be attempted directly to the host pointed to by the domain's A/AAAA records, as per [RFC 5321 § 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5.1):

> If an empty list of MXs is returned,
> the address is treated as if it was associated with an implicit MX
> RR, with a preference of 0, pointing to that host.

`mail.gongin.com.tw` has one A record pointing to a server that accepts SMTP connections. (Which is expected, since the server *is* named "mail", after all.)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  I too am able to verify that that host is accepting SMTP connections.